# Problema con cardinalidad cero en Bases de Datos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, diagrama-er

Yo conocía 3 tipos de cardinalidad

- uno a uno
- uno a muchos
- muchos a muchos

Pero acabo de encontrarme con una cardinalidad que lleva 0
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Es realmente necesaria esta cardinalidad?** Lo poco que pude entender es cuando la entidad puede no estar ligada necesariamente a otra. La verdad es que no la veo muy útil.

**¿Mi diagrama está bien hecho?**
**¿Cómo debería usar la cardinalidad con 0?**

Comment: Y si el cliente es nuevo y no hizo ningun pedido todavia, cuantos pedidos tiene?

Comment: y no es cero a muchos.. es muchos a muchos, incluido 0

Comment: No la ves muy util? Imagina que unas órdenes de compra o fabricación se asignan a uno o varios equipos. Imagina ahora que creas 100 de esas órdenes y todavía no están asignadas. Entonces, todas esas órdenes tienen `FK_Equipo_Orden = null`, o, dicho de otra manera, **una orden de fabricación puede estar asignadas a cero o más equipos.** De igual manera, puedes crear N-Equipos, y no tienen integrantes, todavía, o **un equipo puede tener cero o más integrantes**

Comment: Y voto por cerrar esta pregunta. No tiene respuesta/ está basada en opiniones.

Comment: Que la respuesta sea teórica no implica que esté basada en opiniones. El OP se interesa por la diferencia entre diferentes cardinalidades mínimas y eso es algo con lo que se lleva trabajando desde hace más de 40 años

Comment: Pues, las preguntas '*¿Mi diagrama está bien hecho? ¿Cómo debería usar la cardinalidad con 0?*', me suenan a opinión.

Comment: Arriel, yo te recomiendo que agarres un diccionario, en caso de que no tengas uno, busca en internet la palabra "opinión" y después de haberla buscado intercambiamos ideas.

Comment: Tampoco perdamos las formas. Te dejo un enlace en el que se explica la cardinalidad mínima y la notación que estás usando para que puedas reformular la pregunta y tenga menos aspecto de ser objeto de opinión (es algo que pasa mucho con las preguntas sobre modelado de datos, por eso aquí se prefiere el código, que es  más conciso): https://ikastaroak.birt.eus/edu/argitalpen/backupa/20200331/1920k/es/DAMDAW/BD/BD02/es_DAMDAW_BD02_Contenidos/website_53_cardinalidad_de_entidades.html